# Hydrolysis equilibrium of urotropin

Tags: equilibrium, hydrolysis

In a test I was asked why the hydrolysis equilibrium of Urotropine (Hexamethylenetetramine) in neutral solution lies far on the side of the reactants. Well I had no idea and I'd be very glad if somebody could give me an answer on that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Urotropine hydrolysis]

Small amount of acid is required for hydrolysis.
As a result ammonium salt and formaldehyde are produced.

Update:
It can be explained with enthalpy of reaction [Wiki Enthalpy of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_reaction). 
To calculate it, enthalpy of each  reactant required. 
From wiki: ΔH(C6H12N4)=-99.2kJ/mol, ΔH(H2O)=-285.8kJ/mol, ΔH(NH3)=-45.94kJ/mol, ΔH(CH2O)=-115.9kJ/mol; 
ΔH(reaction)=6*ΔH(CH2O)+4*ΔH(NH3)-ΔH(C6H12N4)-6*ΔH(H2O)=918kJ/mol;

As ΔH(reaction) is large, positive number, a lot of heat required for this reaction, as a result, equilibrium is far on the side of the reactants.

Comment: Yeah, but were is the acid? In your equation, you use water as reactant. While water can be seen as a very weak acid, it does have a pH of 7 which is neutral. And the question was, why the equilibrium in neutral solutions (in Water) lies on the left side. So I don't see the question being answered here :/

Comment: Probably the "in neutral solution" mean that urotropin should react with water. Acid binds molecules of ammonia, so hydrolysis become possible.

Comment: Yes, it does, but that's not an explanation why the equilibrium is *far* on the side ot the reactants. If it would react with the water, the equilibrium would displace.

Comment: It can be explained with enthalpy of reaction [Wiki Enthalpy of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_reaction). To calculate it, enthalpy of each  reactant required. From wiki: ΔH(C6H12N4)=-99.2kJ/mol, ΔH(H2O)=-285.8kJ/mol, ΔH(NH3)=-45.94kJ/mol, ΔH(CH2O)=-115.9kJ/mol; ΔH(reaction)=6*ΔH(CH2O)+4*ΔH(NH3)-ΔH(C6H12N4)-6*ΔH(H2O)=918kJ/mol; As ΔH(reaction) is large, positive number, so a lot of heat required for this reaction, as a result, equilibrium is far on the side of the reactants.

Comment: Tha'ts a pretty good argument, but a reaction happens voluntary if ΔG < 0. As we all know ΔG = ΔH - TΔS and ΔS should be pretty big in this case (7 molecules react to form 10 molecules). But you may be right because ΔH is really big and up to a significant temperature, ΔS will not be bigger, so the reaction shouldn't happen voluntary.